# React Refs- Differentiate Between Refs in Same Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, anime.js

I apologize for the somewhat misleading title, but I didn't know how to summarize my problem. Basically I'm using a combination of refs and anime js, an animation library, to add animations. I have a NotificationBar component that renders a list of Notifications, and when a user clicks delete on one an animation plays and it gets deleted. The problem is anime js uses targets like:

```
handleDeleteNoti = notification => {
    anime({
        targets: this.notiRef,
        opacity: [1,0],
        duration: 500,
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{this.props.clearNotification(notification._id)}, 450)
}
```

the `notiRef` in the targets is targeting all notifications (even though their DOM elements are different), so when one is deleted the animation plays on all of them but only one is deleted. Is there a  way to differentiate between DOM nodes? I tried adding unique names to each with no results.

List render:

```
const notifications = this.props.notifications.map((item, index)=>{
        return(
            <Notification 
                item={item} 
                clearNotification={this.props.clearNotification}
                key={index}
            />
        );
    });
```

Notification component:

```
<div 
    className={styles.notification}  
    style={{borderLeft: '5px solid '+color}}
    ref={node=>this.notiRef=node}
    name={this.props.item._id}
>
//Notification Content
</div>
```

Comment: From where is `handleDeleteNoti` function called

Comment: In the same class as `Notification`, and it is called when the user clicks delete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Refs Array:

```
this.state = {
  notiRef: this.props.notifications.map(() =>
    React.createRef()
  ) /* Other State Vars */,
};
```

Then add these refs to your component:

```
const notifications = this.props.notifications.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <Notification
      item={item}
      clearNotification={this.props.clearNotification}
      key={index}
      ref={notiRef[index]}
    />
  );
});
```

Finally pass the Refs Array to anime.js

```
handleDeleteNoti = (notification) => {
  anime({
    targets: this.notiRef,
    opacity: [1, 0],
    duration: 500,
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.clearNotification(notification._id);
  }, 450);
};
```

Comment: The ref is undefined when passed to the Notification component, it seems the ref isn't being initialized to each notification.

Comment: You can not pass ref and access it via props. Check this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html